# Create dictionary and list based on key/value input

Tags: python

I am struggling to find a way to create a dataset may mixed with dictionary and list
The requirement is based on the entered key, add the key/value pair in either dictionary or list.
For example,
user entered key/value pair as a/1, the data will be saved in a dictionary(dic1), now dic1 = {'a':1}; then user entered b/2, because a!=b, so data will be saved in dic1 as well, now dic1 = {'a':1,'b':1}.
If user entered a/3, because a==a, we need a new dictionary(dic2) and a list(list1), dic2={'a':3} and list1=[dic1, dic2]. If user entered b/4, the data will be saved in dic2 and dic2={'a':3,'b':4}, list1=[dic1, dic2]. If user keeps entering key/value pair, as long as the key does not equal any existing key in dic2, all the data will be saved in dic2.
If user entered a key equal to any exising key in dic1 or dic2, a new dic3 will be created and same rule will apply to them until user stops entering data.

The code I put here obviously does not work. any sample code or algorithm I need to follow are welcome.

```
dic1 = {}
dic2 = {}
list1 = []
def collectinfo(continue_collect):

  global list1
  global dic1
  global dic2
  continue_collect = input("\n\rEnter yes to continue and no to stop: ")
  while continue_collect == 'y':
    inputkey = input("\n\rEnter key: ")
    inputvalue = input("\n\rEnter value: ")
    if inputkey not in list(dic1.keys()):
      dic1.update({inputkey: inputvalue})
      # list1.append(dic1)
      print("s")
      print(dic1)
    else:
      # print(list1)
      print(len(list1))
      if len(list1) == 0:
        list1.append(dic1)
        dic2.update({inputkey: inputvalue})
        list1.append(dic2)
      else :
        dic2.update({inputkey: inputvalue})
        print(len(list1))
        list1[len(list1)-1] = dic2
        print(list1)
        dic1 = dic2.copy()
        print("m")
        print(list1)
        return collectinfo("y")

collectinfo("y")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a strange use case you are describing. I think it worth thinking it again.
But, let's assume it is correct for now.

I quote you :

> If user entered a key equal to any exising key in dic1 or dic2, a new dic3 will be created

It looks like you need a list of dictionnary. Something like :

```
list_of_dictionnary = []
already_inserted = False
for a_dictionnary in list_of_dictionnary:
  if not inputkey in a_dictionnary :
    a_dictionnary.update({inputkey: inputvalue})
    already_inserted =True
    break
  if not already_inserted :
    new_dictionnary = {inputkey: inputvalue}
    list_of_dictionnary.append(new_dictionnary)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.